# What does idiom 'hippo in a haystack' mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I am aware of idiom 'needle in a haystack' which means something hard to get. Is 'hippo in a haystack' opposite of it?

Comment: Where did you see this? Link? context of full sentence/paragraph?

Comment: It's *not* an "idiom" - it's just someone's larky twist on the *needle* version. Presumably meaning something so obvious you can't be unaware of it (cf [*an elephant in the room*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/an-elephant-in-the-room), which *is* an idiomatic standard).

Comment: @Mitch I heard it in a movie and I don't really remember. I just need a general sense of it.

Comment: As FF said, this is not a 'set phrase', it is a one-off, it is just someone being clever, and everyone is expected to understand the comparison with 'needle in a haystack', namely something really easy to find.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's what i thought and it looks i was right. )

Comment: @Mitch yeah it seems you are right.)

Comment: I'd like to have closevoted this as "Too Localised" (because as @Mitch says, it's just a "one-off pun/witticism"), but that reason is no longer available to us. On the other hand, I don't think the one existing "Primarily Opinion-based" closevote would stand up in court - it's a *joke*, which all native speakers would be expected to understand in exactly the same way.

Comment: Easy? It's extremely rare to find a hippo in a haystack.

Comment: Now that it's been mentioned, I see of course that it's a reference to _needle in a haystack_; but my first thought was that it was a humorous twist on _bull in a China shop_, the image being one of a hippo completely disintegrating a haystack by stomping around in it.

Comment: Reminds me of a joke I heard when  I was about 10 years old:  *Why do elephants paint their toenails red?  So they can hide in cherry trees.  Have you ever seen an elephant in a cherry tree?  No?  That's how well it works.*

Comment: Personally, I'd consult my mother on this one- after all, only Ma stands between the idiomatic and the idiotic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agree. I fact, I only found it here: https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22hippo+in+a+haystack%22

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Comment: Stick a very long needle into the haystack.  You'll find the hippo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression *hippo in a haystack* does not appear on the *[Ngram corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hippo%20in%20a%20haystack%2C%20hippo-in-a-haystack&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)*.

1. The first use of hippo in a haystack on the internet seems to appear on September 22, 2013 in [Seton Magazine's](http://www.setonmagazine.com/family/kids-corner/hippo-in-a-haystack-color-in) *Hippo in a Haystack Color-In* campaign:

[image]... Why is the hippo in the haystack? Why is the chicken doing with the hammer?

2. At around the same time, Dakota Riemersma won the MI Rock 2013 Junior Writer contest with a story entitled *[CRYSTAL FOREST](http://www.mirockclubspages.org/pb/wp_b951d151/wp_b951d151.html)*, in which she used the expression:

> We pulled into a clearing and there it was, Crystal Forest. First of
>   all I only saw three trees and they stuck out like a hippo in a
>   haystack.

This usage seems to approach the meaning of the idiom *[stick out like a sore thumb](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+out+like+a+sore+thumb)*:

> Fig. to be very obvious.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.

3. It appears in a *[comment by exelion](http://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/2h3moz/3_afghan_soldiers_have_gone_missing_from_base_in/)* on an article about missing Afghan Soldiers:

> Three people that will appear of middle eastern descent to most
>   Americans disappear in the middle of New England. First off, that's
>   like finding a hippo in a haystack. In some parts they might be the
>   only non-white for miles.

Again, this seems to be the exact **opposite** of the idiom finding a *[needle in a haystack](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Needle+in+a+Haystack)*:

> An item that is very hard or impossible to locate,

4. Currently, Jahanna Shilden has a database listed on *[Github.com](https://github.com/johanneshilden/hippo-in-a-haystack)*:

> **hippo-in-a-haystack**
>
> Experimental in-memory data store designed for multi-node replication.

This moniker also seems to play on the idea that things will be easy to find in the database.

---

**Conclusion:**

Although it has not reached the level of idiom, the expression plays very closely with two well established idioms. Since it employs imagery that is superior to *stick out like a sore thumb*, it is quite likely to catch on with a clear meaning:

> clearly visible; obvious; easy to find.